# Inserting BLOB as stream much slower than inserting byte array

Tags: oracle, spring, hibernate, blob

I have the following scenario: A client is uploading a file to a server. The file is stored 
via Hibernate into an Oracle database. Until recently, the entity which modeled the file had a `byte[]` array attribute for modeling the Blob. We changed that to an `InputStream` because we didn't want to have the whole file in the RAM of the server. In the near future, we expect more users uploading larger files, so RAM indeed is an issue.

I did some performance tests, and so far the results show that streaming is roughly 1.8 times slower compared to inserting a byte array. Here are some results for inserting a 100MB file for 10 Iterations:

```
Method       Mean Duration [ms]  SD [ms]
---------------------------------------
Byte Array   10733.0             264.0
Streaming    18089.0             913.0
```

Communication between client and server is done with Spring RMI, and the streaming of the binary data itself is done with [RMIIO](http://openhms.sourceforge.net/rmiio/). Because of the use of RMIIO, we had to write our own Blobtype, where we unwrap the binary from the client and push it into the binary stream of the blob. The code for this you can see below.

Things I have done so far:

- Just to narrow down where the problem lies, I unwrapped the RMIIO stream in the service method and put it into a byte array, then saved it to the database. Doing it that way, it yields the same performance as using the byte array all along. So the performance drain does not come from the RMIIO package, but rather somewhere between server and database.
- Changing the buffer size has very litte impact on performance

Can anyone share some insight into to why inserting a stream is so slow compared to inserting a byte array?

My configuration:

- Spring 3.1.1
- RMIIO 2.0.0
- Hibernate 3.6.10
- Oracle 11.2.0.1.0
- Oracle Driver for JDBC 10.2.0.5.0

Old Entity with byte array (inserting is faster):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MYBINARYOBJECT")
public class MyBinaryObject {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Lob
    private byte[] bytes;

}
```

New Entity with input stream (inserting is slower):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MYBINARYSTREAMOBJECT")
public class MyBinaryStreamObject {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Type(type = "MyBlobType")
    private RemoteInputStream bytes;

}
```

Our Custom Blob type:

```
public class MyBlobType extends AbstractLobType {

    @Override
    protected Object nullSafeGetInternal(ResultSet rs, String[] names, Object owner, LobHandler lobHandler)
            throws SQLException, IOException, HibernateException {

        RemoteInputStreamServer server = new GZIPRemoteInputStream(lobHandler.getBlobAsBinaryStream(rs, names[0]));
        return server.export();
    }

    @Override
    protected void nullSafeSetInternal(PreparedStatement ps, int index, Object value, LobCreator lobCreator)
            throws SQLException, IOException, HibernateException {

        BufferedInputStream stream = null;
        try {
             ((RemoteInputStream) value).available();
             stream = new BufferedInputStream(
                    RemoteInputStreamClient.wrap((RemoteInputStream) value, RemoteRetry.NEVER), 16384);
             lobCreator.setBlobAsBinaryStream(ps, index, stream, -1);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new MyStreamingException();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: At a quick glance it looks like you're trying to optimize along multiple axes at the same time (low memory and high performance) and wondering why you can't have your cake and eat it too.  Local memory is going to be available for faster access than a stream and that's before considering the additional integrity verification that would be associated with streaming.